# easy-peasy computed does not take inputs

Tags: redux, easy-peasy, redux-selector

The Redux library easy-peasy has a function called `computed` which is an alternative to standard Redux selectors:

```
import { computed } from 'easy-peasy'

const model = {
  session: {
    totalPrice: computed(state => state.price + state.tax)
  }
}
```

And then the selector is called in the component like this:

```
import { useStoreState } from 'easy-peasy'

function TotalPriceOfProducts() {
  const totalPrice = useStoreState(state => state.products.totalPrice)
  return <div>Total: {totalPrice}</div>
}
```

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to pass inputs to the selector. If I need a specific object in an array in the state, I can't pass the ID of the object as an input. My only option is to do this on the component side. Redux selectors have the advantage of being functions, so I can pass inputs to be used in the selector logic.

Anyone use easy-peasy come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't pass the ID of the object as an input

To enable this, you have to return a [function as your computed property](https://easy-peasy.vercel.app/docs/api/computed.html#supporting-runtime-arguments).

Here is an example, exposing a computed function `getTodoById`:

```js
import { computed } from 'easy-peasy'

const model = {
  todos: [],
  getTodoById: computed(state => {
    // Note how we are returning a function instead of state
    //      
    return (id) => state.todos.find(t => t.id === id)
  })
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
import { useStoreState } from 'easy-peasy'

function Todo({ id }) {
  const getTodoById = useStoreState(state => state.getTodoById)
  const matchingTodo = getTodoById(id);
  // ... etc
}
```